# How to add Dask dataframe with different index and column

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I have two csv files. The first one may be very large, and the second one is small. Each one saves some values like `pandas.DataFrame`. Since the first file maybe so large that can not be read into memory. I decide to use `Dask` to process these two files.

What I want to do is to merge the two files. If the index and column is same, then I will add the two values. While add new column or index. For example, I have two files like:

file1:

```
,col_1,col_2,col_3
row_1,1,2,3
row_2,2,4,6
```

file2:

```
,col_1,col_2,col_4
row_1,1,1,1
row_3,2,2,2
```

Finally, I will get a new file like this:

new_file

```
,col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4
row_1,2,3,3,1
row_2,2,4,6,0
row_3,2,2,0,2
```

Then what is the most convinient or efficient way to do this by `Dask.DataFrame`?
Is there any other solutions to process such two files(The first one is so large that cannot be read into memory)?

Answer (score 0):

To do this correctly your two dataframes will need to be indexed by the column that you want to join on.  If that column is named `0` then you probably want to call

```
df = df.set_index(0)
```

on both dataframes.  If the rows in that column are sorted then this will require a full read through the data (but this can be done in small space).  If the rows in that column are not sorted then this will be fairly expensive.